# multiple columns in a single parameter

Tags: sql

Been working on a assignment for a while now and I am on my wits ends. The problem I am having is that I need to have multiple columns from a table within one parameter in order to pull a report based on the person's initials. This is what I have.

```
WHERE (tblWarehouse.Employee + tblWarehouse.Employee2 +tblWarehouse.Employee3 = 
   CASE
      WHEN ISNULL(@Employee, 'ALL') = 'ALL' THEN 
      tblWarehouse.Employee + tblWarehouse.Employee2 + tblWarehouse.Employee3
    ELSE @Employee
  END)
```

when I run the query, it pulls information when I enter the employees initials that has been entered in columns one and two. However, it does not pull anything from column three. Is there another method that can be done to get this information? Thnak you so much in advance.

Comment: I take it that only one of the three columns is ever populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that you're trying to do this?

```
WHERE
       'ALL'                  = @Employee
    OR tblWarehouse.Employee  = @Employee
    OR tblWarehouse.Employee2 = @Employee
    OR tblWarehouse.Employee3 = @Employee
```

Just bear in mind that this won't be able to use a single index to seek out your results.  The rational is long winded, but the following can be more performant...

```
SELECT
     blah
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM tblWarehouse WHERE 'All'     = @employee
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tblWarehouse WHERE Employee  = @employee
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tblWarehouse WHERE Employee2 = @employee
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tblWarehouse WHERE Employee3 = @employee
)
    AS tblWarehouse
INNER JOIN
    whatever
 ...
```

this can then use different indexes for each of the UNIONed queries, avoiding having to scan the whole table every time, and instead just using quick seeks through the indexes.

Comment: Thank you very much! seeing you explanation allowed me to try a different method and I got it working! Please enjoy your weekend and have a great day!